# Jackson @JsonIgnoreProperties isn't working on referenced class property?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I am trying to make a model (`Request`) class that would ignore a nested class's property it references. And I was told that I cannot modify referenced model (`User`) in any way, so what I had tried was to ignore its property from the `Request` model.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Request {
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"id"})
  User user;
}

// class I cannot modify
@Data
@Builder
public class User {
  String id;
  String name;
  ...
}
```

In the payload, I am still seeing id serialized & deserialized so the annotation clearly doesn't work. It seems to work fine if I place it at the class level of `User` but since I cannot modify `User`, I've also tried:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"user.id"})
public class Request {
  User user;
```

None of above works. The doc is saying

> Starting with 2.0, this annotation can be applied both to classes and to properties

I am using Jackson 2.10.2 in a Spring Boot project. What am I missing?

Comment: You are ok with your example, i'm running the same and it works, could you try a local example in a main method with `ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();` and `mapper.writeValueAsString(object)`

Comment: @MarcoPens I did `Request request = mapper.readValue("{\"user\":{\"id\": \"a\", \"name\":\"b\"}}", Request.class);` and `id` is still getting deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class who extends User as bellow:

```
public class MyUser extends User {
    @JsonIgnore           
    String id;     
}

@Data
@Builder
public class Request {
  MyUser user;
}
```

Comment: I wish. but actual model is a lot bigger and don't want to duplicate the entire class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running this test and works:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Request {
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("id")
    User user;
}

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    String id;
    String name;

}



public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();

        final Request value = Request.builder()
            .user(User.builder()
                .id("qw423432")
                .name("asdasdjsadjasdasd")
                .build())
            .build();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(value));

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"user\":{\"id\": \"a\", \"name\":\"b\"}}", Request.class));
    }

}
```

Do you see any difference with your test?

Comment: what does your `System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"user\":{\"id\": \"a\", \"name\":\"b\"}}", Request.class));` print?

Comment: It prints this `Request(user=User(id=null, name=b))`, is this the response that you are looking for?

Comment: mine prints `Request(user=User(id=a, name=b))` ...lol

Comment: did you double check that your are using `jackson-databind` & `jackson-core` in the same 2.10.2 version?

Comment: I just tested it use `jackson 2.9.7` and got the same result as @Marco Pens.

Comment: It is using Spring Boot 2.2.3 with starter-web so it's not explicitly defining Jackson version. it comes with jackson-core, and jackson-data both as 2.10.2